# On matrix derivatives

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'm a newbie in convex optimization and I need to understand how we differentiate matrix and vectors (norms also).

So, how can I calculate gradient and hessian of these two functions? [Images of equations are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rnXC.png)

Basically, I don't understand how to bring huge formulas obtained after differentiation to a standard form. All norms are standard norms in $R^n$

Comment: Use the chain rule, for both. The chain rule states that the derivative of a composite function $h = g \circ f$ at a point $p$ is the linear function $t \mapsto g'(f(p)) f'(p) \cdot t.$

Comment: @WillM. I tried to do this actually. Can you please specifically describe for this task what of this is what and how to count their differentials? Since I do not quite understand, for example, what is $g$ and $f$